# How to Print Record Set Using an Array?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

My Codeigniter model retrieves two records of record set. That is correct.

I tried to print those two records in HTML view.

## Controller

```
public function printFuel($id){     
        $this->data['printData']=$this->Fuel_model->directFuelById($id);                
        $this->load->view('/template/directFuel/printFuel',  $this->data);        
}
```

## Model

```
public function directFuelById($id) {       
        $this->db->select('store_item.item_name, tbl_direct_fuel_details.fuel_qty');
        $this->db->from('tbl_direct_fuel_details');
        $this->db->join('tbl_direct_fuel', 'tbl_direct_fuel_details.direct_fuel_id=tbl_direct_fuel.direct_fuel_id', 'inner');

        $this->db->join('store_item','tbl_direct_fuel_details.item=store_item.item_id');
        $this->db->where('tbl_direct_fuel.status=1 and tbl_direct_fuel_details.direct_fuel_id="'.$id.'"');
        $this->db->order_by('tbl_direct_fuel.direct_fuel_id','DESC');
        $q = $this->db->get();
         if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $q->result();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

## View

```
    <?php
    if (!empty($printData)) {
        $printData = $printData[0];
    }
    ?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Fuel Order::Vehicle Management System </title>



</head>
<body onload="window.print()">
<body>

    <?php
    if (!empty($printData)) {
        ?>       

           <p style="position: absolute;top: 20cm;right: 14cm"><?=$printData->item_name?></p>
           <p style="position: absolute;top: 20cm;right: 11.5cm"><?=$printData->fuel_qty?> Litres</p>

        <?php
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

But it's printed only the first record. If I used, var_dump($printData); exit(), the following output can be got.

```
["item_name"]=> string(5) "DOT 3" ["fuel_qty"]=> string(4)
"1.00"
```

## Desired Output

Need to print two records in HTML view as follows

```
+-----------+----------+
| item_name | fuel_qty |
+-----------+----------+
| DOT 3     |     1.00 |
| DOT 4     |     2.00 |
+-----------+----------+
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: *"But it's printed only the first record. "* Check if the second line is correct in the html by checking the html source code in the browser.. If it is try it without the inline css, the absolute position to align seams to be misused here..  Also a [html validation](https://validator.w3.org/) check first also might help as html with validation errors can misbehave..

Comment: @Raymond. The absolute position is placed correctly

Comment: ... did you try all mine suggestions in less then one minute? ...

Comment: @Raymond. Yes I tried

Comment: Great then i have no idea annymore as this is not much code to work with ... See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections *"Help others reproduce the problem/Proof-read before posting!"* -> *"Try reproducing the problem yourself, in a fresh environment and make sure you can do so using only the information included in your question."*

Comment: .. also you sure you enabled Codeigniter to run in debugging mode so you see errors and notices?

Comment: @Raymond. No it has no errors. First record printed correctly. Didn't show the second record

Comment: Yes i know, but we going around in circles, provide more details of the problem.. Question is simply unsolvable with this limited information..  And try more debugging yourself what does `if (!empty($printData)) { var_dump($printData); exit()`  give is `fuel_qty`  in there for example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two records, the first is stored in a variable called `$printData` and you show its `item_name` and `fuel_qty` attributes. However, if you have two records, then you will need to loop the collection which contains your records, and display its values.

EDIT

You only take into account the first record at

```
if (!empty($printData)) {
    $printData = $printData[0];
}
```

If `$printData` is not empty, then its first element will be assigned to it. Remove the `if` above and change your subsequent PHP code, you should end up with something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fuel Order::Vehicle Management System </title>



</head>
<body onload="window.print()">
<body>

    <?php
    if (!empty($printData)) {
        foreach ($printData as $item) {
        ?>       
           <p style="position: absolute;top: 20cm;right: 14cm"><?=$item->item_name?></p>
           <p style="position: absolute;top: 20cm;right: 11.5cm"><?=$item->fuel_qty?> Litres</p>

        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @mcode, you should be providing more information and do a `if (!empty($printData)) { var_dump($printData); exit() ` so we know for sure what `$printData` is it seams you are not listing to the comments i made before..  **More or less when you provide more information you help us helping you .**.

Comment: If I used, <?php if(!empty($printData)){
                    foreach ($printData as $rows){ ?>   instead of <?php if(!empty($printData)){,  the first record printed twice by over printed (Twice)

Comment: @Raymond. I did, if (!empty($printData)) { var_dump($printData); exit() as you mentioned. It outs the values of two records in the array correctly.

Comment: @mcode can you edit your question and paste these results into there?

Comment: @Raymond. I added my Controller & Model and modified the question

Comment: @mcode thank you, but again: can you append the result of var_dump($rows) to your question?

Comment: @Lajos. I did that. Pls see on modified

Comment: @mcode based on the new information you have given I have edited my answer. Can you take a look?

Comment: @Lajos. Correct. But first & Second record over printed each other

Comment: @mcode this seems to be a design error. If the second element was printed, then the logical problem that you were asked about was solved and now you have another problem. Maybe you would like to ask a separate question about the design issue that you have now.